# Чем чревато много времени для свойства setIntegerProperty, метода onCreate для Android?

Tags: phonegap, android, cordova, java

Вот приложению не хватает времени чтоб подгрузиться на устройстве, выдает ошибку, ответ нашел в добавлении методу onCreate свойства setIntegerProperty с большим интервалом. Мне интересно если я поставлю большой интервал в 2 минуты или даже в 5 минут,

- 1) чем это может быть плохо для
     пользы дела?
- 2) Приложения станут больше мучить
     мой сервер?
- 3) У меня подозрения что приложение
     так долго грузит инфу с
     гугло-серверов? Если это так мне не о
     чем беспокоится?

Вот сам код, он работает, но `super.setIntegerProperty` у меня повторяется два раза, я не уверен что это правильно,

- 4) если это не правильно, то как
     написать правильно?

  `@Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
      super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 120000);
      super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 3000);
   }`

Comment: Вы забили указать ключевое слово - PhoneGap, не так ли?

Comment: loadUrl случайно не в основном потоке происходит?

Comment: KoVadim, я не стал указывать что использую PhoneGap, я подумал что это он не при чем. Но ошибка CordovaWebView: TIMEOUT ERROR! имеет место быть, но если времени поставить 90 секунд то она не появляется.

Comment: Роман Захаров, скорее всего в основном, его нужно в отдельный выводить?

Comment: Все мимо, будем ждать хорошего ответа)

Comment: "Хорошего" ответа не будет. Ответ @KoVadim лучший (в контексте того, что вы предоставили)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@Gennady](/users/14027/gennady) а люди открывают, видят похожее на типичный код, но вот только метода `setIntegerProperty` нет. Ни у активити, ни у других объектов.

По пунктам

1. это плохо тем, что это PhoneGap (это мое мнение)
2. а кто его знает. По приведенному коду- нет.
3. html файл оно грузит с ресурсов программы. Сервера гугла тут ни при чем. `setIntegerProperty` используется для разных целей.
4. Нужно посмотреть внутрь `file:///android_asset/www/index.html` и подумать, почему ему нужно столько времени на загрузку.